# H2 in-memory database error “Data conversion error converting” when using JAVA UUID as primary key

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, h2, uuid

I got following error when using UUID generated by Java with Spring Data and uui2. And different of other questions here, the UUID is generated by Java, not by the database.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
Data conversion error converting "X'aced00057372000e6a....72c41427e' 
(MYTABLE: FIELDID UUID NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
insert into mytable (field1, filed2, fieldid) values (?, ?, ?) 
-- (?1, ?2, ?3) [22018-192]
```

I had 1.4.192 H2 Version on pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

H2 Database got the following new feature on version 1.4.193

```
PR #353: Add support for converting JAVA_OBJECT to UUID
http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html
```

So, I just needed to update my H2 Version on pom.xml to 1.4.193 or major to fix my problem.